# Tree node design in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: tree, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I want to design a base tree node class from which other entity classes can derive, I thought it would be like this:

```
public abstract class BaseTreeNode
{
  public string Id{get;set;}

  public string Name{get;set;}

  public string ParentId{get;set;}

  [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
  public BaseTreeNode ParentNode{get;set;}
}

public class MenuNode:BaseTreeNode
{

}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work when try to build some hierarchies with MenuNode class. It threw a SqlException:Invalid object name 'dbo.BaseTreeNode' when I called SaveChanges method.

I thought the problem was about the property 'ParentNode' as it's an abstract class.
So, how should I design my classes in this case with entity framework 4.1 code first.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think the problem is the `ParentNode` property. The model is valid (except `PrarentId` which is, I guess, only a typo). The problem must be somewhere else. Can you show 1) your DbContext with the DbSet properties, 2) any Fluent mapping if you have one, 3) the code which throws the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this approach will be performance. You may want to store multiple types of trees in the DB (Menu/SubMenu, Category/Subcategory), but this type of inheritance will cause all of them to be stored together in a single table. See this question: [What are the pros and cons of one master base table which all entities inherit from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139855/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-one-master-base-table-which-all-entities-inherit-f)

The question is whether it will ever be necessary to query all types of nodes, regardless of the type of tree.

Comment: Actually i think you're wrong Loren, EF will generate a table for each derived type, so he should a table called MenuNode in the db and whatewver other node types he creates, the base type is effectively only used in a c# context to allow the clr to build a complete object

Comment: No, I just gave this a try. The default behavior is table-per-hierarchy inheritance, meaning that all subclasses are stored in a single table, and a discriminator column is used to distinguish the subclass. In this example, the resulting table is named BaseTreeNodes, and the discriminator column is defined as "[Discriminator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL"

Comment: How peculiar ... I recently wrote a basic Document Management System with EF Code first taking this approach in my C# code. I ended up with 3 classes (FileSystemObject, Directory, File) with the latter 2 inheriting the first, and I got 2 tables in the db (Directories, Files).