# What are the pros and cons of one master base table which all entities inherit from?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework Database first approach to create my domain model.

I am considering creating a base table EntityBase with the base properties in:

```
 PK
 CreatedDate
 CreatedBy
 ModifiedDate
 ModifiedBy

 etc.
```

Using Table Per Type inheritance I will end up with a single table in the Database linked to all other entity tables:

```
EntityBase {
 EntityBase_PK => Identity PK
 CreatedDate
 CreatedBy
 ModifiedDate
 ModifiedBy
}

DerivedEntity1 {
 DerivedEntity1_PK => FK relationship to EntityBase on EntityBase_PK
 Property1 
 ...etc
}

DerivedEntity2 {
 DerivedEntity2_PK => FK relationship to EntityBase on EntityBase_PK
 Property2 
 ...etc
}

...etc
```

I believe this will work fine with Entity Framework, but I am concerned if this is good design from a Database point of view.

The obvious benefit I can see is that I get a unique PK for all entities across the whole database, but I am concerned that having every update hit the EntityBase table could be a performance concern as well as have impact with respect to table locking.

Thoughts?

Comment: All I can say is you are definately normalizing your data.  However remember whenever you will need to query off the Base for the Created and Modified fields, you will need to join the base table, which will have one row for every row in every table.  This could get expensive.  Perhaps reconsider the purpose and what you are trying to solve.

Comment: You said, "The obvious benefit I can see is that I get a unique PK for all entities across the whole database." I've never seen a requirement that said anything like, "An ID number used for a Vendor must never be used for a Customer, an Address, an Order, an Order Line Item, a Web Page, or a Cat."

Comment: @JohnHartsock: Creating an abstraction doesn't have anything to do with normalization.

Comment: as ladislav said, performance would be a problem, you dont really have to map your base class to a table though, just create auditing columns in all tables (except pure join tables), it will also keep the dba happy

Comment: As far as unique key across all entities, I agree this isn't an immediately obvious benefit, but I believe it does help with things like providing a generic entity search across all entities - e.g. Salesforce does something like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest problem will be performance. What you described is called TPT inheritance and until .NET 4.5 with [next version of EF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/25/generated-sql-improvements-for-tpt-queries.aspx) is out this will be the scenario with [very inefficient queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx).

In case of `ObjectContext` API it has one additional cons. You cannot have `ObjectSet` of derived type so you will end with single object set for all entities.

If you want nice OOP concepts define interface with your fields and implement that in all your entities but do not bind your entities with inheritance which span both conceptual and storage model. Even TPC is not very nice solution because it still requires unique primary keys among all tables => it leads to guids.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as it relates directly to EF which I am using (I have edited the original question to make this clear). Based on this I am going to avoid inheritance in my Database model and look into ways of doing this with Interfaces in the Object model. Any ideas how I could implement intefaces on T4 Template generated entities in a way that would not get overwritten each time I regenerate the entities?

Comment: You can simply modify the template to add interface to all your entity classes (if all of them use these fields). If you need to do it selectively it is better to define your own partial parts of entity classes to implement interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

OO concepts rarely translate over to relational databases. As a DBA, I have spent more time cleaning up attempts to shoehorn OO concepts into a relational database than anything else (and not because I'm a purist, but because they didn't work.)

If you want unique PKs across all entities, look at guids (or sequential guids)

It's not going to hurt anything for those columns (CreatedDate, ModifiedDate etc) to be in each entity table (in fact, that's correct design) You will, however, see terrible query plans as you join back to your base table again and again.

In short, I'd advise against it.

Comment: Thanks for the DBA perspective on this - it is kind of what I suspected hence my reluctance to go ahead. It seems the more I use EF it wants me to mould my DB in a very specific way which may well be not optimal for performance or good database design.

Answer (score 0):

> The obvious benefit I can see is that I get a unique PK for all
>   entities across the whole database.

Could you not achieve this by using a HiLo algorithm or similar for your identities?